# Violence and War in life

Tags: philosophy-of-war

[Link:](http://brainly.com/question/1894164) Does the violence make us understand some idea? If so, what? What is the purpose of such detail? 
I'm doing a report for the novel *Ender's Game*. The large role in this novel is violence and war.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Clausewitz "War is politics by other means", I think war shows that it is ultimately impossible to limit the will to power.

In the Genealogy of Morals, Nietzsche points out how even the commonality of losing, and being oppressed, can be leveraged into a source of power if the ranks of those oppressed are large enough.  And even that power can be abused.  Christianity has been used to convince a lot of people to kill.  And it is based on empathy for suffering and oppression, at its origin.

War is, most basically, the mass refusal to obey the taboo against killing for power.  And the fact it still exists shows us that ultimately, no rules apply.  We have to choose them.

If, as in the case of cultures wholly alien to one another, there is no means of negotiation, there are no rules.  Politics has no limits because it can create 'alternative means' when it finds the ones it has are not working.

Enders Game cheats, because it shows only effective war.  Card has his protagonist isolated first from knowledge of his actions, and then from their consequences.  So it is also, to some degree, a good illustration of how horrifically easy asymmetric warfare is.  Even though the sides are somewhat easily matched, the bugs elicit no sympathy, so Ender's sentimentality is not confronted with actual suffering.  By completely failing to identify with one's enemy, one can be led to drastic means easily.

Comment: I have the same beef with Heinlein's "Starship Troopers", effectively side stepping the real issues because the war he invents is way too clean. Haldeman's "The forever war" makes a little bit more sense (although the implicit homophobia in it hasn't aged well).

Comment: @AlexanderSKing Card tries really hard to hold Ender responsible in the next few books.  But ultimately he fails.  Guilt is not horror, and the whole setup is just too clean.  OTOH war is becoming more like that: consider the average drone pilot, or anyone else who takes part routinely in operations that kill 150 people on the other side for every one on ours.  It may be problematic in a good way.

Answer (score -1):

Mmmh. Yes. At some point. It does show that human are imperfect by conception, they make mistakes and don't always learn about it.

Often, war is due to failure of rational argumentation (words can't be a solution to every single problem, even if we would like it to be this way).

There is another point. We do see, de facto, see commonly the subsequent happening: the conqueror erases the memory of the conquered in the population's spirit. Look at monuments. Many, such as the Arc de Triomphe de l'Étoile, in France, is builded for commemoration of French's victories. People do often forget that we read "Comment on the Gallic War", which is written by a war winner, Caesar. But what would tell us the populations that were vanquished, what would they point out about Julius Caesar, would it really by so glorious, without abuse. Good thing to think on.

Comment: Yeah. Now that is really a good thing to think over. Thank you!